# Django Dynamic Class Based Generic Views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

We've got a lot, a lot of views that utilize simple generic views that we used to loop over in urls.py and point to the same function based generic view. Now that we're moving to class based generic views, we need to replicate this functionality and we're being forced to move all of the logic into the urls.py file, like this:

```
GENERIC_VIEWS_EDIT = ['ModelOne', 'ModelTwo', 'ModelThree', 'ModelFour', 'ModelN',]

for model in GENERIC_VIEWS_EDIT:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',

        url(r'^%s/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' % model.lower(), never_cache(staff_member_required(UpdateView.as_view(
            model=eval(model),
            context_object_name='object',
            form_class=eval('%sForm' % model),
            template_name='edit_form.html',
            success_url='/yay/'
        ))), name='edit-%s' % model.lower()),

    )
```

While this works fine, I disdain having all of this "view code" in the urls.py file. Furthermore, if I need to override a method for one or two of these N models, this implementation makes that impossible.

Is there any way I can pass the model as an argument and move my generic view back into views.py, something like this?

```
GENERIC_VIEWS_EDIT = ['ModelOne', 'ModelTwo', 'ModelThree', 'ModelFour', 'ModelN',]

for model in GENERIC_VIEWS_EDIT:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^%s/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' % model.lower(), UpdateView.as_view(model=model)), name='edit-%s' % model.lower()),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. This logic belongs in your View.

Since you're using Class Based Views, you can just subclass UpdateView and override the `__init__()` function with custom logic:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'edit_form.html'
    success_url = '/yay/'
    context_object_name = 'object'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyUpdateView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_class = eval('%sForm' % self.model)
```

Comment: It's a class, it's a class, it's a class! I just need to keep telling myself that and it'll sink in eventually. Thank you, Kyle.

Comment: It is easier to override self.get_form_class. There, you just return the form class